# How can I use a thread pool to off-load a processing from a Netty handler

Tags: netty

I have a server proxy implemented with Netty 4.0.27 to support a set of custom protocols. One of these protocols processes results from a server with a simple two-handler pipeline before returning messages to the client: a custom LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder followed by a handler that does some non-trivial processing of each message/frame. The proxy will be stress tested soon on a high CPU/core server and I’d like to take advantage of these cores by passing messages from the handler to a thread pool for processing, retrieving processed message, and sending them to the client (in the right order). I do not see how to do this within a Netty handler due to it being a callback in nature.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an `EventExecutorGroup` while adding handler to the pipeline:

```
pipeline.addLast(group, "handler", new MyBusinessLogicHandler());
```

See **Building a pipeline** section at http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html